# CRA react - redux : componentWillReceiveProps is triggered, but no rerender

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use the create-react-app to do a minimal application which connect to my plex, and I did the login form.

I've added react-router, redux and redux-saga so far, and time has come to make the first POST to my backend.

All worked as wanted, except one thing : the container doesn't rerender after a failed login, but it goes throught the `componentWillReceiveProps` method.

Here is what happened :

[image: Here is what happened]

the thing is : the store *has changed*, because if I type something triggering the re-render, the error message will show up.

I can also see, in the redux DevTool that the store has, indeed, the error from the server. Finally, the server error is also in the `componentWillReceiveProps` log.

I don't know what to try now. You can see all the code here : https://github.com/kai23/askimovie/tree/add_plex_login

- [the login reducer](https://github.com/kai23/askimovie/blob/add_plex_login/client3/src/reducers/login.js)
- [the container](https://github.com/kai23/askimovie/blob/add_plex_login/client3/src/containers/Login/Login.js)
- [the action](https://github.com/kai23/askimovie/blob/add_plex_login/client3/src/actions/login.js)

Thanks for any help given :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out this code or update it, your component is re-rendering but its not the state that has changed when you want to do the the update it's your props. So when the props change this runs and returns true, because it only checks one at a time. It's not checking state change and props change at the same time.

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextState.loginInput !== this.state.loginInput ||
      nextState.passwordInput !== this.state.passwordInput ||
      nextState.capsLockOn !== this.state.capsLockOn ||
      nextState.inputPasswordType !== this.state.inputPasswordType
    ;
  }
```

Comment: That's a perfect catch. Thank you for avoiding me multiple headaches.

Comment: Its all good mate, I've done this so many times. The lifecycle can be a bit hard. I get what you're trying to do though. You should check out the PureRenderMixin. It should take care of all of it for you. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html